# Message UI for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, chat, framework, windows-phone

I'm trying to write a messaging app for Windows Phone 8, but I'm having some problems:

I have to design the chat page (the one with the bubbles), but I would not like to rewrite or reinvent that, so I would like to use an already existing framework for Windows Phone. I looked around and I found a very good framework, Telerik's libraries, but unluckily it is not free.

Can anyone suggest me a free message UI for WP?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to write your app for Windows 10, the [Telerik Controls for UWP](http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui) are now free / open source.

Comment: But is that for Phones?